# how to push different variables in array in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Below there are 6 variables with some values , I have to push this data in Array "socialMediaDetail" in below format ,how can I do that ?
Please help suggest . This is kind off example ,Please help .

```
// Below 6 variables .
const Twittername = 'twitter';
const Twitterlink = 'HARIRAM @twitter.com';
const facebookname = 'facebook';
const facebooklink = 'VarnaHERO @facebook.com';
const linkedInname = 'linkedIn';
const linkedIlink = 'linkedIn @linkedin.com';

// in below format I have to store in array . 
const socialMediaDetail = [{
  "name": "twitter",
  "link": "HARIRAM@twitter.com"
}, {
  "name": "facebook",
  "link": "VarnaHERO@facebook.com"
}, {
  "name": "linkedIn",
  "link": "linkedIn@linkedin.com"
}];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing that is to just use the variables while initializing the `socialMediaDetail` array:

```
const socialMediaDetail = [{
  name: Twittername,
  link: Twitterlink
}, {
  name: facebookname,
  link: facebooklink
}, {
  name: linkedInname,
  link: linkedIlink
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

just initialize an array with value as a variable name.

```
const socialMediaDetail = [{
  "name": Twittername,
  "link": Twitterlink
}, {
  "name": facebookname,
  "link": facebooklink
}, {
  "name": linkedInname,
  "link": linkedIlink
}];
```